# How to Properly Destroy an Intersection Observer?

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructor, intersection-observer

I am currently wrapping the IntersectionObserver API into a Svelte action. Part of this requires cleanup in a `destroy()` function, below is what I have.

```js
function observe(node: HTMLElement, key: string) {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(nodes => {
        locations[key] = nodes[0]!.isIntersecting;
        locations = locations;
    });
    
    observer.observe(node);

    return {
        // this is the focus of my question
        destroy() {
            observer.unobserve(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything else I need to do to destroy the IntersectionObserver?

Comment: As long as there exists a reference pointing to `observer`, it won't be eligible for garbage collection, so you need to mind what's holding that `destroy` method

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`observe()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/observe):

> To stop observing the element, call `IntersectionObserver.unobserve()`.

So I think there's nothing more to be done.

Another alternative is to use [`observer.disconnect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/disconnect) to stop watching all of its target elements.